# Why my lenovo laptop isn't taking any special partition

Tags: lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair

I brought a lenovo laptop with DOS. So, I had to install OS on my own. So, when I was installing it, Windows, Lenovo took some special partitions.

I had some problems with the OS so, I thought to re install it and thus first deleted all the partitions and created new ones.
This time lenovo didn't take any partitions. I wonder why that happened.

Is there any problem with my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I wish you were a bit more specific with " special partition "..
Anyway, i believe it was the recovery partition of Lenovo. And no, nothing's wrong with your laptop.